# How does a "pulling grip" wire puller work?

Tags: wiring

This seems like it would be very useful when pulling wires, I'm just not grasping the concept. I'm also wondering if anyone has had success with it.

[image]

Comment: Hmm yet another “I saw this at Menard’s, what do you think”… did https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/156978/judd-heess get question-banned?

Comment: If you don't grasp the concept, how can you possibly make a judgement it works be useful?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." ([Off-topic questions listing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) from the [help]).

Comment: Asking how a poorly-packaged tool works (and, by inference, how it would be used) strikes me as **a very valid question**. I've found myself in that situation many times, particularly at wholesale-type suppliers. @whatsisname, your point eludes me. One doesn't need to understand how an airplane works to realize that it has benefits.

Answer (score 5):

The concept is similar to the Chinese finger trap, see picture below. It's a braided tube that grips the wire and allows easier pulling because you don't have to bend the wires you're pulling around the hoop on a fish tape. They're really helpful when pulling close to the maximum number of cables in a conduit. It's not really useful for small number of conductors in larger pipes. They come in a variety of different sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are extremely useful when pulling pre-terminated cables through a raceway - I use them all the time for pulling pre-termed fiber through innerducts because all the pulling force is applied to the cable jacket, not the plug.

I'm not good enough to terminate fiber in the field if I want it to be useful after.  Using a pulling grip allows you to fish the cables without tearing the ends off.

Answer (score 1):

It's only useful is specific situations where you need to fish a relatively thin wire/cable through a narrow opening.  It's basically a piece of braid that you push through the opening, and then you insert the wire/cable into the "core" of the puller and stretch it tight so that the puller "collapses" on the wire/cable.  Then pull the puller all the way through.

I've never used one so I have no idea how effective it is.

Answer (score -1):

I"ve used fish tapes in the past and really don't like them.   Now when I need to pull wires thru conduit I use a thin but strong rope with the end tied to a plastic shopping bag (or other means) and suck it thru the conduit with a shop vac. Then cut off the bag and attach the wires well taped (and I mean WELL TAPED) to the rope and pull away. This is best done as a two person job:  one person putting a firm tug on the rope and the other on the other end pushing in the wires and ensuring there are no tangles. Every time I've used this method it's been successful.   Regarding the "Chinese Finger trap", I'll try that someday, but have never used it, so I can't comment as to their effectiveness.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question then, does it? :)

Comment: @isherwood  I guess not, but others already had   answered.  I just didn't to be a member of the Department of Redundancy Department. :)  So I thought I'd just add something to the post.  This could also (maybe) be considered an XY question.